TypeError: string indices must be integers при переборе данных из массива
Есть массив данных:
data = {
    "pages": 1,
    "items": {
        "1": (1, 2, 3),
        "2": (4, 5, 6),
        "3": (7, 8, 9)
    }
}

Они перебираются через:
for d in data["items"]:
    udata = data["items"][d]
    print(udata)

Вывод:
(1, 2, 3)
TypeError: string indices must be integers


Во-первых, код синтаксически некорректный из-за незакрытой скобки. Во-вторых, с закрытой скобкой код работает без ошибок, проблема не воспроизводится

И на всякий случай  - массива (и списка, если вы его имели в виду) здесь нет. Словари и кортежи.

@andreymal, даже с закрытой скобкой почему-то не работает

@MBo массив это словарь

@hecker0508 ваша ошибка говорит о том что data["items"] -- это строка. Но как такое получилось... непонятно.

Ваш код работает корректно (возможно ваш код использует какие-то другие данные и с ними не работает).
Но я бы написал по другому:
data = {
    "pages": 1,
    "items": {
        "1": (1, 2, 3),
        "2": (4, 5, 6),
        "3": (7, 8, 9)
    }
}


for k, v in data["items"].items():  # (1)
    udata = v
    print(udata)


По умолчанию в цикле for (если перебирается словарь) перебираются только ключи. .items() возвращает пару: ключ, значение (k и v). Мы используем v.


Так, может, перебирать values() ?

@MBo можно и так. Но я написал по другому чтобы можно было бы использовать и ключ.
